# About char and $x+x=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider $ R$ a *finite ring* endowed with the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ and $|R|$ is an *even number*, let's say $2k$.

We donote:

Let $e$ be the identity element of $(R,\cdot)$ and $a$ be the identity element of $(R,+)$

We denote:

$$e_k=e+e+...+e$$

where we have $k$ summands in total.

Prove that if $R$ has a unique element, $x\ne a,$ such that $$x+x=a$$ then $$x=e_k \:\text{ and } e_k\ne a$$
and if it has zero or more than one element such that
$$x+x=a$$ then $$e_k=a$$

I have just read a chapter about ring theory and I observed that in a finite ring, the char(R) cannot be equal to zero, therefore the char(R) is a positive integer but I have come to no useful and relevant results.

Comment: For example, suppose $R = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  This is a finite ring of order $4$ so with $k=2$.  In this ring, *all four elements* satisfy $x+x=0$.  This is your second case, in which how do I interpret "$k=0$" as a correct conclusion?

Comment: In your case, $k=1+1$ (where 1 is the identity element of $(\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2,\cdot)$ which is $(1,1)$), since $k=2$. Then $k=(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,0)=0$, the identity element of $(\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2,+)$

Comment: That clarifies it.

Comment: Also, (+1).  I've enjoyed working on this, but I'm stumped at one point in my argument (and I know I'm making it harder than it is).

Comment: You can post what you managed to do in the comments, if you would like, maybe somebody may help you continue.

Comment: $k=1+1+...+1$ where $1$ is the identity elemenst of $(R,\cdot)$

Comment: @TonyK  you're missing what I missed.  You have to interpret $k$ as $k \cdot 1$ in the right places.

Comment: And to be clear:  you are not assuming that $R$ must be commutative, right?

Comment: @Randall: we are given that $|R|=2k$. This is unambiguous. But then it seems that $k$ is _redefined_ to mean the characteristic of the ring, although this is not entirely clear. I stand by my comment!

Comment: $R$ is not commutative.

Comment: I changed the variables in the post to make it clearer. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a unique nonzero $x \in R$ such that $2x=0$. Since $|R|=2k$ we certainly have $2k=0$ in $R$, so $k+k=0$.  I claim $k \neq 0$.  Suppose for a contradiction that $k=0$ in $R$, so $kr = 0$ for all $r \in R$.

Factor $k$ as $2^r k'$ where $k'$ is odd. There's a unique element of order 2 in the abelian group $(R, +)$, so $(R, +) \cong C_{2^{r+1}} \oplus A$ for an abelian group $A$ of odd order $k'$.  That contradicts $k$ annihilating $R$: it can't even annihilate the cyclic summand $C_{2^{r+1}}$.

If there are no elements of additive order 2 then since $k+k=0$ we must have $k=0$.  (It's not possible to have no elements $x$ such that $x+x=0$ since $0+0=0$, probably the "nonzero" hypothesis is missing).

Suppose there is more than one element of order 2. Factor $k$ as $2^rk'$ again. The abelian group $(R, +)$ of order $2^{r+1}k'$ can't have a $C_{2^{r+1}}$ factor (because it must have non-cyclic 2-primary component), so it has exponent dividing $k$, so $k=0$ in $R$.

Comment: This is the argument I was trying to make work.

Comment: $(R, +)$ is the additive group of $R$. $\oplus$ is direct sum of groups.

Comment: Why do we have $(R,+)≅C_{2^{2r+1}}⊕A$? I do not quite understand this solution. Can somebody explain it to me? For instance $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z$ is not isomorph with $C_{2^{2}}⊕A$ since it doesn't have an element of order 4.

Comment: Yes, I guess this answer needs to be a little more detailed in the second and the last paragraph, especially the part with the annihilation and the cyclic summand and why $C_{2^{r+1}}$  factor must have non-cyclic 2-primary component and what does 2-primary component mean.